# Pass variable to input field

Tags: javascript

How do I pass a variable to an input field on an url. I want the javascript to enter my email adress into an input field on certain URLs. Is this even possible? I know 1Password does something like this with usernames and passwords.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Yes. Via a browser addon perhaps.

Comment: Also userscripts (Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey etc) can do this

Comment: @devnull69 - Yes. Or a user script as you said.

Comment: @techfoobar How is this possible with a browser addon? I can't find any documentation on this. So it's not like I'm not even trying ;)

Comment: @user2755352 - Browser addons can access and manipulate the DOM of loaded pages - irrespective of the domain the pages are served from. Which in your case would mean filling input boxes with custom values. Addons like greasemonkey makes this easier by letting you concentrate on the things you need done instead of the addon related boilerplate.